# Scrapy: Pass arguments to spider that is defined in /spiders directory

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a script that uses `CrawlerProcess` to run a spider of class `MySpider` defined in `mybot/spiders/myspider.py`. 
Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
# in main.py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

items = []
settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl("joe", domain='dictionary.com')
def add_item(item):
    items.append(item)
dispatcher.connect(add_item, signals.item_passed) # adds result from spider to items
process.start()
```

.

```
#in /spiders/myspider.py
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from mybot.items import MyItem

name = "joe"
allowed_domains = ["dictionary.com"]
start_urls = ["http://dictionary.reference.com/"]

for sel in response.xpath('//tr[@class="alt"]'):
        new_item = MyItem()
        new_item['name'] = sel.xpath('td/a/text()')[0].extract()
        yield(new_item)
```

Now, I want to change the program so that I can pass some other `start_url` to the spider from `main.py`. It looks like I can pass the `allowed_domains` argument to the spider via

```
process.crawl("joe", domain='dictionary.com')
```

but I don't know how to generalize that.

I think I have to redefine the `MySpider`'s constructor to accept an optional argument, but it doesn't look like the spider is created in `main.py`
(and in fact, the command new_spider = MySpider() returns the error `global name 'MySpider' is not defined`.

So my question is twofold:
How do I change the spider's constructor?
How do I pass the `start_urls` to the spider from `main.py`?

Or is there perhaps a different solution altogether?

Comment: It looks like some parts of the code are missing from myspider.py. Can you fix that? Thanks.